# Can't find subdocument by _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to retrieve a subdocument by id. My abbreviated schema is:

```
OfferSchema.add({
  counterOffers: {
    type: [OfferSchema]
  },
  ...
});
```

I've tried a few different methods:

```
const offer = await this.offerModel.findById(parentID).select('_id counterOffers');
const counterOffer = offer.counterOffers.find(obj => obj._id === _id);

// and also

const counterOffer = offer.counterOffers.find(obj => obj._id === Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id));

// returns undefined for counterOffer
```

also:

```
const counterOffer = await this.offerModel.findOne({ 'counterOffers._id': _id });

// returns the parent object, not the subdocument
```

but neither will return the subdocument. I have tripe-checked that my IDs are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do  you need to [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) the counterOffers field?

Comment: @Joe What I need to do is retrieve one sub document from the counterOffers array by its _id field.

Comment: You've declared the array to contain a schema.  That probably means mongoose only actually stores an array of DBRef.  To convert that to something you can use, you will need to populate the array.

Comment: Hmm. When I look at the data previously using MongoDB Compass, it appears there are full documents in the array. I’m away from my computer for the evening, but I’ll try running a populate() on the field

Comment: Does the last example query return all of the counterOffers?

Comment: The last example returns the parent document, not the sub document

Comment: So it doesn't contain any counterOffers?

Comment: It does, but as I demonstrated in the first two examples, I’m not able to use a function like find() to get the object. I will try using populate() in conjunction with find() first thing in the morning

Comment: OK, that's different, if it is returning the sub-documents along with the parent, use the find on `'counterOffers._id'`, and project `'counterOffers.$':1`.

Comment: @Joe adding the projection works. If you want to create an answer to that effect, I'll accept it. Thank you very much for the help!